# How to access ethereum/client-go shell outside docker container

Tags: docker, ethereum, go-ethereum

I have just started learning Blockchain and following a [YouTube tutorial](http://youtube.com/watch?v=QCvL-DWcojc&t=2827s) . In that tutorial he installed ethereum by cloning the repo , but I have installed the ethereum/go-client using docker as per the instructions given in [official documentation](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/install-and-build/installing-geth#run-inside-docker-container) . I am beginner to Docker too . When I run the docker container using `docker run -it -p 30303:30303 ethereum/client-go` command , my terminal looks like this :-
[image]

Now I want to make an account using `personal.newAccount()` command . But where I should run this command ? Container is not providing me any shell where I can run this command .

I have searched about this lot on internet but doesn't get a solution , all of them is showing how to install geth using docker only .

Please help me . I have just started learning blockchain .

Thank

Answer (score 0):

Start a container with

```
docker run -it -p 30303:30303 ethereum/client-go account new
```

it puts you straigth to new account creation.